# Can I use cache decorator to save result of any function call?

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators, memoization

I'm aware that `@cache` decorator is used as quick way to implement memoization

Is is possible to use it on other contexts, like for deterministic functions (that return the same result provided the same arguments)?
Should I avoid it if the function is non-deterministic?

This is what the doc says

> Returns the same as lru_cache(maxsize=None), creating a thin wrapper around a dictionary lookup for the function arguments

I wonder what happens when the function takes no arguments

Comment: have you tried?

Comment: You shouldn't cache a non-deterministic function because you might not get the same output for the same inputs (any or none).

Comment: A deterministic function that takes no arguments would have to return a constant value.  I suppose `@cache` might still be useful in that situation, if calculating that constant value takes a long time.